# position:sticky left:0 breaks when adding a parent div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a layout where the header gets scrolled out but the nav and footer are kept. Here's the link to it:

https://play.tailwindcss.com/LiIq5be2Wz?size=360x640

Here's the same code written in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cdxqsfu4/

I already have it working but the framework I'll be using this on needs to have an `app` div. After adding it (or uncommenting it, in this case), only the `top:0` part seems to be sticky, not the `left:0`. Is there a way to fix this?

EDIT: Here are the specifications I need:

- The scrollbar should span the entire view, including the header and footer.
- The header needs to be hidden when scrolled down.
- The nav should be sticky to the top-most and left-most side of the screen.
- The nav should span the entire width of the screen.
- The footer should be sticky to the bottom-most and left-most side of the screen.
- The footer should span the entire width of the screen.
- The header needs to be outside of the `app` div.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to change the order of your markup. You should nest your `header` with the other divs and set one of them to `overflow-auto`. Doesn't matter which one. Using two `overflow-auto`'s was the only way to get it to work with your previous structure, which loses the header scrolling.

See it working on [Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/eLc8DV9jli?size=654x640).

Comment: Adding overflow:auto only puts the overflow on the `app` div, not the entire page. I need the header to be hidden when the user scrolls up

Comment: @b12629 see edits.

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more specific, my bad. I've edited my main post to list what I need.
For the new code, I need the header to be outside the app div.

Comment: So you want that, but without that structure? Why cant it be inside the div if it works just fine?

Comment: Everything outside the app div will be prerendered by the framework. I need the header to show because the app may take a few seconds to load

Comment: @b12629 okay that makes sense. I think if you set `position-absolute` class on `<header>` with your old structure it should fix your issue. Let me know though cause I’m on my phone and haven’t tested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242295/discussion-between--and-b12629).